# Redux react not re-rendering component after state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have posts and each post has comments, when I am adding a new comment the change is displayed (rendered) until I refresh the page manually but I can see in redux-dev tools that ADD_COMMENT action is being called and state of post is changing. What I want is to show the comment on page as soon as it is added to database. (State change and rendering works fine on Post Add,Delete,Update).
[image: DIFF]

[image: STATE]

posts.js (contains all the posts):

```
class Posts extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    posts: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    getPosts: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    deletePost: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getPosts();
  }
  onDelete = (id) => {
    this.props.deletePost(id);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.props.posts.map((_p) => (
          <Post _p={_p} onDelete={this.onDelete} key={_p.id} />
        ))}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
const mapToPropTypes = (state) => {
  return { posts: state.posts.posts };
};
export default connect(mapToPropTypes, { getPosts, deletePost })(Posts);
```

post.js (Single post):

```
class Post extends Component {
  handleDelete = (id) => {
    this.props.onDelete(id);
  };
  render() {
    var _p = this.props._p;
    return (
      <div className="row pt-3 pb-5">
        <div className="col-lg-8">
          <h1 className="mt-4">{_p.title}</h1>
          {/*.... POST RELATED INPUTS ....*/}
          <hr />
          {/* Comment Form */}
          <CommentForm postID={_p.id} />
          {/* COMMENT COMPONENT */}
          {_p.comments.map((_c) => (
            <Comment key={_c.id} comment={_c} />
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default connect()(Post);
```

commentForm.js:

```
class CommentForm extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    commentBody: "",
  };

  static propTypes = {
    addComment: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const comment = {
      body: this.state.commentBody,
      post: this.props.postID,
      name: this.state.name,
    };
    this.props.addComment(comment);
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { name, commentBody } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="card my-4">
        <h5 className="card-header">Leave a Comment:</h5>
        <div className="card-body">
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Title:</label>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                value={name}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                className="form-control"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <textarea
                className="form-control"
                name="commentBody"
                value={commentBody}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
                rows="3"
              ></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, { addComment })(CommentForm);
```

comment.js:

```
const Comment = (props) => {
  const _c = props.comment;
  return (
    <div className="media mb-4" key={_c.id}>
      {/* ... COMMENT RELATED OUTPUTS ...*/}
    </div>
  );
};

export default connect(null)(Comment);
```

reducer:

```
case ADD_COMMENT:
      state.posts.map((_p) => {
        if (_p.id === action.payload.post)
          _p.comments = [..._p.comments, action.payload];
      });
      return state;
```

addComment function:

```
export const addComment = (comment) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/comments/", comment)
    .then((res) => dispatch({ type: ADD_COMMENT, payload: res.data }))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the problem is due to the state that is not considered as modified.

I saw 2 things in your reducer :

1. You use .map() function, and this function return a new array with the result of your modification. Try to stock this value first.
2. Then, in your reducer, return a new copy of your state, with the new value of your posts.

Like this :

```
let modifiedPosts = state.posts.map((_p) => {
        if (_p.id === action.payload.post)
          _p.comments = [..._p.comments, action.payload];
      });

return  Object.assign( {}, state, {
                posts: modifiedPosts 
            } );
```

Comment: As per your suggestion I modified my code but still same result? No i am using for loop instead of map and storing my modifiedPosts in other variable still same resullt? https://jsfiddle.net/zc5m9oqu/

Comment: You are also directly modifying the state, that is not the way redux works. The best way to do that is to make a deep copy of your array :
let modifiedPosts = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( state.posts ) );

And then work on this array.
See this documentation for in-depth information : https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it. I will try to look deeper into how states are managed in redux. Thanks